# How to run CLion with SFML and CMake on Linux? Errors in Make and audio?

Tags: linux, cmake, linker-errors, sfml, clion

I'm pretty new to installing, rearranging files, and somewhat writing code on Linux. When tasked to install CLion along with SFML and CMake, I've come into a lot of problems figuring out how to make them work. I'm currently using a Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid(copied straight from what I saw), so if there's anything specific about that, that'd be nice to know too.

The problem in particular that I'm encountering is when I decide to run my file. I get these set of errors.

```
/usr/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object `/home/user/Development/sfmlbuild/lib/libsfml-audio.so'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/sfml_project.dir/build.make:88: sfml_project] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/sfml_project.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/sfml_project.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: sfml_project] Error 2
```

This is what I have in my CMakeLists.txt as well, which I assume locates most of the SFML files, so CLion can use them.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
set(PROJECT_NAME sfml_project)

project(${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -static")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 ${SOURCE_FILES})
else ()
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
endif ()

set(SFML_ROOT "/home/user/Development/sfmlbuild")
cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 NEW)
set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES FALSE)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake_modules")
find_package(SFML  REQUIRED COMPONENTS audio graphics window system)
if (SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
endif ()
```

I'm unsure what to do from here, or if there's anything wrong in particular with how I have my CLion setup. I set my CMake application to the folder where I have my sfml_project. And my sfmlbuild which contains the Linux version of SFML, downloaded from the suit, is in a separate folder which is where the libsfml-audio.so is located inside of. As for the build, execution, and development part of the CLion program, I have the Toolchains to detect the Make, C compiler, and C++ compiler where I also left the profile that's available to default. Maybe those have to do with something that's wrong, but I'm honestly unsure what to do from here.

If anyone can provide me feedback, small or large, then I would greatly appreciate it and try to get back as fast as I can with responses on whether or not I've done certain things.

I furthermore apologize as this is my first time utilizing this website to ask for any questions, so if this is a question poorly done, I accept my inexperience, and I hope to do better next time.

---Edit Update---
I suppose I should've put what the errors were exactly as well, so I'll add them here too.

For make[3]: Error 1

```
# External object files for target sfml_project
sfml_project_EXTERNAL_OBJECTS =

sfml_project: CMakeFiles/sfml_project.dir/main.cpp.o
sfml_project: CMakeFiles/sfml_project.dir/build.make
sfml_project: /home/user/Development/sfmlbuild/lib/libsfml-audio.so
sfml_project: /home/user/Development/sfmlbuild/lib/libsfml-graphics.so
sfml_project: /home/user/Development/sfmlbuild/lib/libsfml-window.so
sfml_project: /home/user/Development/sfmlbuild/lib/libsfml-system.so
sfml_project: CMakeFiles/sfml_project.dir/link.txt
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --green --bold --progress-dir=/home/user/CLionProjects/sfml_project/CMakeFiles --progress-num=$(CMAKE_PROGRESS_2) "Linking CXX executable sfml_project"
//Line #88 is the next one which the error refers to.
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/sfml_project.dir/link.txt --verbose=$(VERBOSE)
```

For make[2], Error 2:

```
# All Build rule for target.
CMakeFiles/sfml_project.dir/all:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/sfml_project.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sfml_project.dir/depend
//The next line is line 76 for which error 2 occurs with make[2].
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/sfml_project.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sfml_project.dir/build
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --progress-dir=/home/user/CLionProjects/sfml_project/CMakeFiles --progress-num=1,2 "Built target sfml_project"
.PHONY : CMakeFiles/sfml_project.dir/all
```

For make[1], Error 2:

```
# Build rule for subdir invocation for target.
CMakeFiles/sfml_project.dir/rule: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/user/CLionProjects/sfml_project/CMakeFiles 2
//The next line is 83 for which make[1] occurs.
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 CMakeFiles/sfml_project.dir/all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/user/CLionProjects/sfml_project/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : CMakeFiles/sfml_project.dir/rule
```

The make error is as follows, Error 2:

```
# Build rule for target.
sfml_project: cmake_check_build_system
//The next line is 118 for the make error.
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 sfml_project
.PHONY : sfml_project
```

I apologize for posting all of this information so late; I still don't quite understand too much, but I hope this gives some more information for aid.

Answer (score 0):

One potential issue is your find_package flag, looking on at a project I've made I used

```
find_package(SFML 2.5.1 COMPONENTS graphics audio REQUIRED)
```

Try putting the version number

another issue, according to this website SFML_ROOT is replaced by SFML_DIR. Hers the website: https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=24070.0

Comment: I checked that out, and changed it to the find_package as well as SFML_DIR, but it doesn't seem to change much in the building errors, other than a 2 line difference which was caused by the change in the find_package. As for what that points to, I don't know.

Furthermore, I apologize, but I changed the original post as well to reflect the exact errors that I obtained. I should have included them upon post creation, but I am new to this process. I apologize, and I thank you for the help nonetheless.

Comment: I don't have too much experience with SFML on Linux so I am not sure what those errors are exactly. But I did find a good source that might help you out [link](https://medium.com/@Rewieer/install-sfml-2-5-1-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-clion-9e0dfe86e87f)

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for this o/. This actually did really help me, and I was able to properly install CMake with this and thus run CLion. Thank you very much.